# A sub-matrix constructed using the row basis and column basis is always non singular

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $A$ is $m\times n$ matrix. Show that $A$ has a non singular sub matrix which is formed by the basis elements of row space and column space.

If I have understood the problem clearly, this means that we try to construct a sub matrix using all the independent rows and all independent columns. These rows and columns will necessarily form bases. We have to show that this sub  matrix should be non singular. So I proceeded this way,
Suppose $rank(A)=r$. Take the $r$ linearly independent rows (they are forming the basis of row space) as the row of a new matrix, say $B$. This is of dimension $r \times n$. Now, this matrix $B$ has rank $r$. So, there should be $r$ linearly independent columns amongst these $n$ columns.

Now, I will choose any $r$ linearly independent columns of $B$. These $r$ columns will be a basis of column space of $A$. Here I shortened the proof. I am using that adding some components in every linearly independent vector still make them independent. And, as they are $r$ in numbers, they must be basis.

Comment: It's correct. Note that there might be more possibilities to choose $r$ independent columns/rows, but this procedure works for any such choices.

Comment: Thank you @Berci